# Excel VBA: Solver not working in loop

Tags: vba, excel, solver, xla

The Solver in the loop works for the first iteration but not rest. The rest of the loop works fine.

```
Sub Macro1()

Sheets("model").Select
Dim i As Double
Dim p As Double


For i = 1 To 10
p = -0.1565 + ((i - 1) * 0.0015)
Sheets("model").Range("J15").Value = p


SolverOk SetCell:="$J$12", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$B$4:$F$4", _
    Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
SolverOk SetCell:="$J$12", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$B$4:$F$4", _
    Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
SolverSolve (True)



Sheets("rec").Select
Range("B1:H1").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("rec").Range(Cells((i + 4), 2), Cells((i + 4), 8)).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Range("C5").Select

Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the Solver will only operate if the sheet is Active, so insert a

```
Worksheets("model").Activate
```

before your first `SolverOk` statement.

```
Sub Macro1()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim p As Double

    For i = 1 To 10
        p = -0.1565 + ((i - 1) * 0.0015)
        With Worksheets("model")
            .Activate
            .Range("J15").Value = p
            SolverOk SetCell:="$J$12", _
                     MaxMinVal:=2, _
                     ValueOf:=0, _
                     ByChange:="$B$4:$F$4", _
                     Engine:=1, _
                     EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
            SolverOk SetCell:="$J$12", _
                     MaxMinVal:=2, _
                     ValueOf:=0, _
                     ByChange:="$B$4:$F$4", _
                     Engine:=1, _
                     EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
            SolverSolve True 
        End With

        With Worksheets("rec")
            .Range(.Cells(i + 4, "B"), .Cells(i + 4, "H")).Value = .Range("B1:H1").Value
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```